# What do these cascade types correlate to?

Tags: java, sql, jpa

So if we have the CascadeTypes from **JPA (Not Hibernate)** of:

- All
- Detach
- Persist
- Merge
- Refresh
- Remove

What do these operations correspond to in terms of SQL?  I'm confused as to how I would convert my SQL code such as:

- on update cascade on delete cascade

  - I think this is the ALL CascadeType?
- on update cascade on delete no action

  - Would this just be the Persist CascadeType since it's not doing anything on delete?
- on update no action on delete no action

  - Would I just not specify any CascadeType's so that the default (no actions) are used?

Thanks!